# How to update a pull request through Github API

Tags: python, git, github, github-api

I want to update the title of a pull request and performing the below to achieve it :- (followed this doc https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#update-a-pull-request)

```
data = {"title": "New title"}
url='https://hostname/api/v3/repos/owner/repo/pulls/80'
token = 'my-token'
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'token %s' % token}
resp = requests.patch(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)

print resp.json()
```

What am I missing ? Please help.

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: @osowskit {u'documentation_url': u'https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.9/v3/pulls/#update-a-pull-request', u'message': u'Not Found'}

Comment: Does your url have owner and repo switched as written above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
import requests

token = "my-token"
url = "https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:number"
payload = {
    "title": "New title"
}

r = requests.patch(url, auth=("username", token), json=payload)

print r.json()
```

Comment: How does it work for you? Your url looks generic. It does not have a hostname like "github.company.com" ?

Comment: Yeah, this solution uses the main GitHub website, not GitHub Enterprise.

Comment: Ok, I am using GitHub Enterprise, and V3 of the API. I can add comments to the same Pull Request through my code using the same token. But while updating the pull request itself, it does not work.

Comment: Actually, my code works as it is. I was using a team level token, and not a personal one. When I use a personal one, I can update my pull request. Follow up question is : Can I edit someone else' pull request through my git token ?

Comment: Ahh great to hear you got a solution! :)
I think there is a setting for that. If you're a maintainer, then you might be able to edit it.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Yes there is some key in the Git Payload too which says maintainer can modify or not (as a Boolean), will look into it. Thanks overall for your help. Appreciate it :)