# Editing GitHub Issues via API

Tags: python, python-requests, github-api

I would like to edit the body of a GitHub issue with the API. I am using a python application an the requests library.

```
url = "https://GHE_server.company_name.com/api/v3/repos/org_name/repo_name/issues/1/"    
payload = {
      "title": "New title"
        }
    response = requests.patch(url, json=payload, headers={}, auth=(_USERNAME_, _TOKEN_), verify=_CA_CERT_)
```

I get the response:

```
{'message': 'Not Found', 'documentation_url': 'https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.13/v3'}
```

I reviewed [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081609/how-to-update-a-pull-request-through-github-api) and that made me change my payload to =json vice data. but I am still running into a wall. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The trailing backslash in the URL was causing an invalid page to be accessed. Removing the slash fixed the issue.